# Microsoft Emotion API for Python - upload video from memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to load a video to Microsoft's Emotion API. Here's my code thus far:

```
import httplib
import urllib
import base64
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

_url = 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognizeInVideo'
_key = '<my key>'
_maxNumRetries = 10

paramsPost = dict()
paramsPost['outputStyle'] = 'perFrame'

headersPost = dict()
headersPost['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = _key
headersPost['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
jsonGet = {}
headersGet = dict()
headersGet['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = _key
paramsGet = urllib.urlencode({})

responsePost = requests.request('post', _url, \
                                data = {'file':open('my_file.mp4','rb').read()}, \
                                headers = headersPost, params = paramsPost)

print responsePost.status_code
```

I am getting back HTTP status code 202, so I think I'm doing most of this right. However, when I wait about 2 minutes and then type

```
getResponse = requests.request('get', videoIDLocation, json = jsonGet,\
                               data = None, headers = headersGet, params = paramsGet)

print json.loads(getResponse.text)['status']
```

,... I get back "Failed". What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I figured out the answer to my own question. Since documentation about the Emotion API is scant, I am sharing my findings below with everyone for the best interest of the community.
The following code returns HTML status code 202 and successfully uploads the video from my local drive:

```
import httplib
import urllib
import base64
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

_url = 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognizeInVideo'
_key = '<my key>'
_maxNumRetries = 10

paramsPost = urllib.urlencode({'outputStyle' : 'perFrame', \
                               'file':'my_file.mp4'})
headersPost = dict()
headersPost['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = _key
headersPost['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
jsonGet = {}
headersGet = dict()
headersGet['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = _key
paramsGet = urllib.urlencode({})

responsePost = requests.request('post', _url + "?" + paramsPost, \
                                data =open('my_file.mp4','rb').read(), \
                                headers = headersPost)

print responsePost.status_code
```